# Multiline JSON String notation

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

I know there are lots of questions on this topic already, but I somehow can find the right solution for my case.

So I want to outsource some user terms in a separate JSON file. As you can imagine those strings are pretty long.

```
{ 
      "term": "Terms and services", 
      "description": "*I´m a 300 words long string, which don´t want to stay in one line*" 
}
```

this would work, as long as it stays in one line- obviously.
But I want this:

```
{
     
      "term": "Terms and services", 
      "description": "*first 30 words* 
                      *second thirty words* 
                      *third thirty words*
                      *...and so on*"
}
```

I already tried inserting backslashes or \n which also doesn´t work (I want the new lines to be displayed in the browser the same way they were written in the JSON document.
Or are these long strings the absolute wrong usecase for JSON? What else could I use with the least effort?

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: How do you `display in the browser`? In `div` tag, don’t you?

Comment: Yeah I know that... I´m working with React and like to keep my components clean. So I´m outsourcing that p-tags to sustain readability of the component, which is why i want to import that JSON file and display it´s contents in my JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the *storage* of data with the *presentation* of that data, these are separate concerns.  JSON only deals with the storage of the data and as such doesn't support splitting a value out over multiple lines, for that your editor of choice should have a word-wrap option.

In terms of displaying the data with embedded line breaks, simply add whatever markup is used by the presentation layer to insert line-breaks, for example:

```
function addLinebreaks(str) {
    return str.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
}

node.innerHTML = addLineBreaks(data.description);
```

Using something like this, any instance of `\n` in your source string is converted to a `<br>` tag in the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**display newline on the web**

You can achieve `\n` breaks with some simple css using the proper value for `white-space`. ( there are many other ways, but this seems the most appropriate approach based on the little data you gave ).

```js
const div = document.getElementById('div');
const json = {
  some_text: "Hello \n there \n I should \n wrap \n lines"
}
div.textContent = json.some_text;
```

```html
<div id='div' style="white-space: pre-line"></div>
```

Read more: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop

**in your code-editor**

As far as I know you can't put multiline strings in a `.json` file.

You can however set your code editor to wrap overflowing text. Maybe there is even a plugin that makes a string wrap after `/n` appears in your code editor - I don't know, but it wouldn't surprise if that exists.

Comment: Hmm, okay, seems like I have to look for some plugins than to show linebreaks in JSON-files, or I´ll have to stay with the syntax of a really long string with "\n"s in it. Thanks!